# get_post_meta doesn't work with variable

Tags: wordpress, loops, custom-fields

The $event_count variable doesn't prints anything, what am i doing wrong?

```
global $post;
$event_count = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'eab_event-bp-group_event', true);

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'incsub_event',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'eab_event-bp-group_event',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'eab_event-bp-group_event',
                'value'   => $event_count,
            ),
        ),
);

$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
        $my_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
} else {

}
wp_reset_postdata();`
```

Comment: Check if `$post->ID` prints correct post id. Also make sure `eab_event-bp-group_event` column exist in post_meta table with that post id.

Comment: @Rikesh the `$post->ID` prints correct post id only if i echo it inside the loop, but outside it prints a 0 and yes that column do exist.

Comment: Where are you putting this code? What post(s) is `eab_event-bp-group_event` tied to?

Comment: @rnevius I'm trying to print the 'events feed' of the current 'group', but it is printing the events in all the groups if i remove the value from `meta_query`

Comment: What template is this code in?